# What is Everyone and Everyone except external users group in SharePoint Online(O365) and what is the difference between them?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups

Can anyone please elaborate on Everyone and Everyone except external users group? I tried adding Everyone group to the Visitors group thought it would include all users but it is not. Some people still requesting for access? Why did it did not include all users?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, please refer to this article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/access-management/grant-everyone-claim-to-external-users

*Starting on March 23, 2018, we are updating the behavior and governance of access by external users in Office 365.
After this change is made, an external user will see only the content that is shared with that user or with groups to which the user belongs. External users will no longer see content that is shared to the Everyone, All Authenticated Users, or All Forms Users groups. By default, content that is granted permissions to these groups will be visible only to your organization's users.*